# Which Machines fall under each category?

Tags: achievements, horizon-zero-dawn

There are four trophies regarding killing one of every type of Machine in each category. However, there is nowhere in-game that tells you *what* category each Machine falls under. The most information I've been able to find was in a [teaser](https://blog.eu.playstation.com/2017/02/10/get-a-detailed-in-depth-look-at-horizon-zero-dawns-amazing-machines/) that introduced a few of the Machines and categorized them.

The teaser categorized the Stormbird and Thunderjaw as Combat-class Machines, the Behemoth as a Transport-class Machine, and the Snapmaw as an Acquisition-class Machine.

I also assume that Watchers and Red-Eye Watchers are Recon-class Machines, for obvious reasons. However, this only covers 6 of the 24 types of Machines, excluding Tallnecks (you can't kill these) and "Corrupted Machines".

The reason I ask is that I managed to go the entire game without killing a single Broadhead, which kept me from getting the "All Acquisition machines killed" trophy, which surprised me, because I didn't realize Broadhead was considered an Acquisition-class Machine (I really don't understand what makes it that, either, but I digress...). That said, which Machines fall under the Acquisition, Combat, Recon, and Transport categories?

Comment: Acquisition I would imagine would be mostly grazing machines, as they are gathering resources. Transport machines make me think of Shellwalkers.

Comment: @DavidYell agreed on acquisition with grazing, but that doesn't explain Snapmaws... also, an argument could also be made that Shell-Walkers are Acquisition since they hoard stuff in their pods, though they're probably Transport, now that you mention it.

Comment: Snapmaw is aquisition from the solar panels on it's back perhaps?

Comment: I can't find any information or lists detailing this all but many people do seem to be running into a problem with the trophy not being rewarded because corrupted versions of a machine don't count towards the kill count.

Comment: @Virusbomb yeah, I tried super hard to find anywhere that catalogued them, but to no avail. The corrupted machine thing is definitely why I was so confused about having never killed a Broadhead, for the record.

Comment: The way I see it, perhaps it's based on the tiers of machines, ex: Sigma, Tau, etc?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf that's possible, but I don't see how Snapmaws are on the same level as Broadheads. Honestly, the Snapmaw and Broadhead categorizations are just really throwing me off.

Comment: I found a video that tells you how to find each type of machine. If you want it, here it is, so you can kill the Broadhead: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Py7_ZdR0rMQ

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I don't think so, we have to kill each machine in 4 different categories but there are 5 override tiers: phi, sigma, rho, xi and zeta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a start, I'll be compiling the machines per category here. These are gained from various sources around the Internet, as well as my own experience. Some are still as of yet unclassified, as their roles could be considered for multiple classifications.

## Acquisition:

- Broadhead
- Charger
- Grazer
- Lancehorn
- Rockbreaker
- Scrapper
- Snapmaw
- Trampler
- Glinthawk

## Recon:

- Watcher
- Red-eye Watcher
- Longleg

## Combat:

- Ravager
- Thunderjaw
- Stormbird
- Sawtooth

## Transport:

- Shellwalker
- Fire Bellowback
- Freeze Bellowback
- Behemoth
- Strider

## Not Applicable

- Corrupted Machines
- Corrupter
- Deathbringer

## Unclassified:

- Stalker

Of course, the easiest way to get all the trophies to pop is to just kill one of each type of machine. As Vemenous mentioned in the OP, corrupted machines do not count towards these trophies.

Comment: If Deathbringers fall under combat, I would assume Corrupters do as well, considering their origins...

Comment: I would agree. At the same time, how do I classify a Glinthawk? They certainly have Recon properties, but are also seen drilling into scrap piles. Same goes for a Stalker and Longleg; are they combat machines, or recon machines (since they have a ping to find you in tall grass)

Comment: I was actually going to say Stalker seems like a Combat machine. Mostly due to the dartgun it has attached to it, but the cloaking could easily serve a reconnaissance purpose (had to check how to spell that).  As for the ping, I want to say there's a third that has that pinger... I seem to remember there being a loading screen tip that mentioned 3 Machines having it.

Comment: I believe it's the Ravager, the Longleg, and Stalker.

Comment: I got "kill all the recon class machines" trophy yesterday after killing my first Longleg, so it seems that it falls under that category, too.

Comment: @pinckerman that makes sense, since they have the recon pulse to see you in tall grass. I'll add it when i get a free moment, or feel free to add it.

Comment: If you figure out what any of the others are, please be sure and update your answer! :D

Comment: Removed Deathbringer from Combat section, I have that trophy but never encountered that machine.

Comment: @pinckerman I disagree, the trophy popped for me once I killed the Deathbringer.

Comment: How is this possible? Were you battling something else when obtaining that trophy?

Comment: no. If I remember correctly (i waited a while to do the story missions, so I had killed all the other machines) the trophy for all combat machines and scanning all machines with the focus happened on my first encounter with the Deathbringer. What other category would it even be in anyway? I suppose it's possible that it isn't part of a category at all, like the Corrupted Machines.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same, it's uncategorized imho. Could this discrepancy be due to a different localization of our games? Feel free to rollback my edit.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf if Deatbringers are N/A, then I'd think Corrupters are, too? Not sure though.

Comment: @Vemonus I would agree, yes. That leaves the stalker... combat or recon I would say, but there's no telling.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I can confirm Stalker falls under one of those categories (I don't own transport and acquisition trophy), but if I have to guess I'll say combat.